# Eclipse WTP platform HTML Editor customization

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp, xtext

At work, it was given to me a modified WTP HTML Editor. It is the package "org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner". We have a problem with the editor and the person that modified it does not work here anymore. I will try to explain the problem.

1. We have Xtext files with an HTML section. We take that section of the Xtext file and show it in the HTML Editor.
2. The HTML Editor has three tabs: the splitted window showing the html preview and the html code, a tab showing only the preview, and a tab showing the whole Xtext file.

What we want is to modify the html in any of those different views, and then, refresh the others.

The problem comes when I edit the html code from the Xtext file since it refresh all the views except the html preview of the splitted tab. I have to close and reopen de file to see the changes.

I have this code in the HTMLEditor class.

```
public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        if(_textEditor.isDirty()){
            _textEditor.doSave(monitor);
            updateFile();
        }

    if(_eventEditor.isDirty()){
        _eventEditor.doSave(monitor);

        FileStoreEditorInput fileStore = null;
        try {
            fileStore = getFileStoreEditorInput(getEditorInput());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        _textEditor.setInput(fileStore);

    }
}
```

The getFileStoreEditorInput method gets the HTML part of the Xtext file and sets it to the _textEditor objects, which refers to the HTML code of the splitted tab.

I don't know where else to look nor if this is of general knowledge.

Thanks!